# Store hash values in url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
Rails 5.0.0.rc1
Ruby 2.2.5 (can update to latest)
```

I'd like to think this is possible. I'm making a `get` request that when a field is selected then the user presses the next button, it goes to another page and that page's url looks like:

```
http://localhost:3000/food/r/new?utf8=%E2%9C%93&id=2&food=Apple&commit=Next
```

This looks ugly, to me. Could it be more nicer to look like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/food/r/new/<some_random_short_string/<name-of-page>
```

I'd imagine the `some_random_short_string` would be a hash then in the controller would have something like:

```
hash = params[:some_random_short_string]
hash[:food] #=> "Apple"
etc...
```

Not sure how to go about this. Any pointers, please?

Comment: Maybe friendly_id gem could help?

Comment: @seph Not really. I may end up, in the url, with many field names.

Comment: Hashing (using MD5 or SHA1) is a one-way trip. You hashes your original data, and you never get them back.

Comment: @Aetherus I have figured, thanks. Found a simple way for this. I forgot the difference between get and post ;)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than deleting my question, I'll answer it as I will come back to it one day.

'get' exposes data in the url so I went for `post`. No need for a hash just use params to store the values.

Once page is submitted, the url will look like: `http://localhost:3000/food/r/new`. In the controller, you use your params:

```
@selected_food = params[:food]
```

**new.html.erb:**

```
<%= @selected_food %> #=> Apple
```